# MVC6 Startup.cs / SignalR - referenced 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions" NOT COMPATIBLE

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5) Web App and want to include SignalR. (Visual Studio 2015, Update 1)

I've added the following NuGet packages.

"dependencies": {

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
**"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta5",**
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
**"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"**
```

},

I've then added the following code in the Startup.cs file
[Startup.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpQi2.png)

As you can see, I have the proper dependency already added for 
**"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"**

If I change the above reference to use any of the *beta* versions for Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, the error message goes away from the Startup.cs file for app.UseSignalR();, but then generates errors for the rest of the code.

**"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta7"**

[referencing beta breaks other references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3geBf.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just wanted to add that I did reference WebSockets as well      app.UseWebSockets();

            app.UseSignalR();          
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

Comment: You can't really mix versions and SignalR was not updated accordingly to work with rc1 bits. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) SignalR is not going to be ready until after ASP.NET 1.0 is released. According to [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/144) it may be possible to use the nightly feeds and get it to build, but there is no focus on updating it, so you will likely run into all sorts of issues.